# Google+ Sign in error in chrome

Tags: google-plus, sign

Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://dev.c.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://accounts.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.

Implementing G+ sign in . This error comes in chrome and rest of the browsers - firefox and safari it works fine. Sometimes it works on chrome as well and some times it fails with above error

Answer (score 0):

All in your exception message: "Protocols must match."
I have solved it by setting "https" protocol for my site and binding to Self-signed SSL certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your cookies. That worked for me.